# FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed on device

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a facebook login on my iOS app. It's working on the simulator but when I try on my device it always fails with a `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed` status.

Do you have an idea about what can make this occurred ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have allowed this application on iPhone Settings>Facebook.